# Removing new line after a particular text via bash/awk/sed/perl

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I would like to remove all the newline character that occurs after a partiular string and replace it with a tab space. Say for instance my sample.txt is as follows

```
foo
bar bar bar bar some text
```

I would like it to be

```
foo    bar bar bar bar some text
```

How do I do this via bash/awk/sed. Do help.

Comment: What happened to "some text"?

Comment: Just missed it, doesn't make a difference I guess.

so the desired output should be

foo    bar bar bar bar some text

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In awk:

```
awk '/foo$/ { printf("%s\t", $0); next } 1'
```

Comment: Woot! Worked in a jiffy. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, that is a typical awk approach. I wrote a sed solution below somewhere among the answers... :)

Comment: For those wondering about the 1 at the end; simply put, it translates to `{ print $0 }` so that lines which *don't* match foo are printed as they are i.e. the basic format is `awk '{/some_pat/ { /* if pat is true */ } { /* if pat is false */ }'`

Answer (score 9):

Here is how:

```
cat input.txt | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/foo\n/foo\t/g'
```

More about why simple `sed 's/foo\n/foo\t/g'` does not work here: http://linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq5_009.html

Comment: You don't need to use `cat`. You could pass the file name to `sed` directly.

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=foo)\n/\t/' input
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "foo\nbar bar bar bar some text"| sed '/foo$/{N;s/\n/\t/}'
foo     bar bar bar bar some text
```

Actually:

```
echo -e "foo\nbar bar bar bar some text"| sed '/foo$/N;s/\n/\t/'
foo     bar bar bar bar some text
```

The latter solution is less efficient but not by much!

Answer (score 4):

The `sed` version looks like

```
#!/bin/sed -f
/foo/{
N
s/\n/\t/
}
```

If this is all you want to do in your sed command, you can simplify the above to a one-liner:

```
sed -e '/foo/N;y/\n/\t/'  <sample.txt
```

Explanation: `N` appends a newline and the next line of input; `y/\n/\t` replaces all newlines with tabs, or `s/\n/\t/` replaces the first newline with a tab.

Note that since `sed` is line-oriented, the newlines in the input are considered line-separators rather than as part of any line (this is in contrast e.g. to Perl).

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe 's/foo\n/foo\t/g' temp2.txt
```

below is the test.

```
243> cat temp2.txt 
foo
bar bar bar bar some text 
pearl[ncm_o12.2_int_x86.@2].244> perl -pe 's/foo\n/foo\t/g' temp2.txt
foo     bar bar bar bar some text
```

Answer (score 2):

Not all tools can do newline replacement. Perl can:

```
cat file.txt | perl -p -e 's/\n/ /g'
```

Comment: mmm 1. you missed the 'foo' requirement. 2. you missed the _tab_ requirement

Answer (score 2):

Mmm. not sure this fits your requirements, but I'd do this in vim:

```
:g/^foo$/join
```

Or, if foo could be anywhere on a line:

```
:g/foo$/join
```

Of course, `:%s/foo\n/foo\t/g` will do nicely too

Comment: Tried this as well! Worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a pure bash example, actually, it is a P{OSIX-compliant Bourne shell example, here you are:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line 
do  
case "$line" in     

  foo )        printf "${line}\t";      
                ;;      
     * )        printf "${line}\n";   
esac 
done <file.txt
```

It is a `while` loop that for each line read by the `read` program stores the line in a variable named `line` (we will refer to it as `"${line}"`), `do` initiates the work in the loop.  We use `case` to check if the line equals `foo`, if it does, we use `printf` to print the line followed by a `TAB` (`printf` does not print the line feed unless you instruct it to), we specify `;;` so it falls through (it does not try another match, `*` would also match `foo` and it would print `foo` AGAIN followed by a newline, so, for all other lines that do not match `foo` followed by a line feed, we use `printf` to print the line with a line feed at the end. `esac` ends the case statement
`done` ends the while loop and the `<file.txt` instruction sends the file `file.txt` to stdin (standard input) of the while loop for `read` to *digest*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you are sure that your string does not contain carriage return (`\r`):

```
echo "$string" | tr '\n' '\r' | sed 's/foo\r/foo\t/g' | tr '\r' '\n'
```

Steps:

- `tr` replaces all line feed (`\n`) agains carriage return (`\r`)
- `sed` replaces all occurences of the string `foo\r` against `foo\t`
- The final `tr` reverses the line feed / carriage return replaceement.