# remove newline character after line starting with pattern

Tags: bash, awk

I found solutions for similar problems but not exactly what I was looking for.
Basically, I want to join two lines into one if first line starts with a given pattern.
From this

```
One
PATTERN bla bla bla
Three
Four
```

to this

```
One
PATTERN bla bla bla Three
Four
```

This "awk" solutions doesn't work.
[Removing new line after a particular text via bash/awk/sed/perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519585/removing-new-line-after-a-particular-text-via-bash-awk-sed-perl): it prints the two lines as one but the second line goes at the beginning and partially overwrites the first line.

**EDIT:**  All these solutions have the same results. To be more clear I'll put the original text.
Original line

```
LOCUS       NODE_10_length_218773_cov_81.1626_ID_>218773 bp   DNA linear
BCT09-MAY-2016
```

Both sed and awk processing return

```
 BCT09-MAY-2016E_10_length_218773_cov_81.1626_ID_>218773 bp   DNA linear
```

But if I redirect stdout to a file seems we are almost there

```
LOCUS       NODE_10_length_218773_cov_81.1626_ID_>218773 bp   DNA linear^M BCT09
```

But where does that ^M come from?

Comment: *These solutions doesn't work* will not be of much use here. But showing us how you modified those solutions to fit to your problem is useful.

Comment: I suspect your source file has been generated on Windows where end-of-line consists in CR+LF whereas on Linux this is just LF. The solution is to remove unconditionally `\r` chars.

Comment: You're right, I didn't encounter this issue before. Everything works after removing \r so it probably count as a duplicated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ORS` output record sparator to do that very easily as

```
awk '$1 !~ /PATTERN/{ORS="\n"} $1 ~ /PATTERN/{ORS=" "} 1'
```

**Example**

```
$ awk '$1 !~ /PATTERN/{ORS="\n"} $1 ~ /PATTERN/{ORS=" "} 1' input
One
PATTERN bla bla bla Three
Four
```

---

Or more simply like,

```
awk 'ORS = $1 ~ /PATTERN/ ? " " : "\n"'
```

**Example**

```
$ awk 'ORS = $1 ~ /PATTERN/ ? " " : "\n"' input
One
PATTERN bla bla bla Three
Four
```

**What it does?**

- `ORS = $1 ~ /PATTERN/ ? " " : "\n"` Sets the `ORS` to space or newline depending on the pattern match.

  Now expression always evaluates to true, in which case `awk` will print the entire input record.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the explanation which is always useful. Still for some reason it almost works (see edit in  main post)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '/^PATTERN/{N; s/\n/ /;}'
```

Comment: Just noticed that this solution is given in the question you link to...you'll need to clarify what is wrong with the solutions given there, since they seem to answer your question.

Comment: To be honest I didn't notice that solution, so thank you for poiting that out. Anyway I just tried and realized that all these a solutions have a common problem that I'll write in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have gnu-awk below solution :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="^$"}{$0=gensub(/bla\nThree/,"bla Three","g",$0);print}' your_file
```

should do it.