# Replace a text with \n character only at a particular line of the text with escape identifier

Tags: perl, unix, sed, tcl, vi

I have tried `sed` and `perl` commands to replace the text but I didn't get expected results. 
For Example : 
I want to replace

```
ABC"\ 
}
else {
....
```

with:

```
ABC"\ 
} else {
....
```

How can I do this? 
Challenges faced are as follows:

1. As it contains escape identifier and `\n` I am unable to search the pattern also.
2. It is not the beginning or end of the file to truncate the particular line and replace.
3. Tried to change with respect to a line number in a file but my requirement is to do for multiple files hence, line number is not constant.
4. Though I can search for `else`. I'm unable to replace the `\n`
5. I have tried the inputs given in [Removing new line after a particular text via bash/awk/sed/perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519585/removing-new-line-after-a-particular-text-via-bash-awk-sed-perl)
   but they do not serve my purpose.

Please give your inputs and help me if there is any other approach for this.

Comment: 'ABC"\ } \n else { '.... to be replaced with 'ABC"\} else { '

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you, we need to know what you have tried exactly. Please [edit] your question and include the Perl and sed commands that you tried to do, and how they didn't work. Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and take a look at the markdown help to learn how to format your question properly. Both lists and especially the code formatting are relevant to your question. Your problem includes exact character sequences, where every space matters. If you don't format it properly, we cannot see what's going on.

Comment: It is hard to understand your question because it appear you want you want to replace one string with the same string.  I think you have a typo in your question.  Please edit.  Also, please include the perl or sed code you tried to we can help you.

Comment: If you're tidying code, then there's usually a code-tidying tool that is semantically correct.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can try

```
sed '/}/N;/\nelse {/s/\n/ /'
```

Answer (score -1):

Tcl solution:

```
set text [string map [list "\\\n}\nelse {" "\\\n} else {"] $text]
```

Replaces all occurrences. Does not write back to variable: you need to assign back as in the example above.

Documentation:
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)